# Open PDF data object in a new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

We're re-doing PDF generation in one of our web applications and for the most part have switched over to jsPDF.

We have a single PDF that is returned from an external request which we then mask the url of and open it in a new tab.

Previously, we were displaying the PDF like this

```
<form target="_blank" action={'/pdf/company?ID=' + this.props.recordId + '&PAGE_ID=' + this.props.pageId}>
        <input type="hidden" name="PAGE_ID" value={this.props.pageId} />
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value={this.props.recordId} />
        <input className="btn3" type="submit" value="Get PDF"/>
</form>
```

I'm able to make a successful request to the same endpoint

```
axios.get(`/pdf/company?ID=${record.id}&PAGE_ID=${this.props.pageID}`)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

And I receive back a response that looks like this

```
data: "%PDF-1.7\n%����\n7 0 obj\n<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20171227143403-05'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 8 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 6 0 R ] /PZ 1 >>\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 2871>> stream\nx���v�6\u0016���\u0014����\u0010·��r�8�5u��3���^0\u0012,s\"�\u000eI�M�~6t )�\u0004{H���^�\u0015�����\u0007�\u0001\u0012\u0014�R\u0013�B׈�\u000f��\u001f��o�k\u0002?o�g���\u0019\u001a\u001dQD\u0019&�/tv�ޜ� O}���\u000fd�\u000f˧\u0019b7����\"�H­��X3),�������#F�xPL_\u0008�%��H�,�Jrm\u0008�\u001a��F\u000b��,Vdy�¡��Q�S�S�\u000c�Hk\u0004�\n�\u000b����ފ�q���n�3P��s�\u001e��Hy\u0004�M\u0018��{��\u007f֚a!��,�׻�QX7a��z�>\u0006k��\u0008\u000cb\n�u�<\u0002�&�0_���g-9f�1\"�|�[\u001e�u\u0013F��w�c�\u0016\u001cF\rj(\r�u�<\u0002�&�0_���g�\u0005�\u001aTP\u001d����(��0�|�[\u001f�5\u00130jP�D��C�\u0011X7a��:D�?k*�\u0011\u0014\u000f̯wˣ�n�\u0008��n}\u000c�D¨A\u0018\u000f̯C�\u0011X7a��:D�;ki%V\u0002\"�A�\u000e��`�\n#��\u0001�\u0018���DX!l����\u0011X7a\u0004�:H�?k�0�@dX~\u001d �º\t#�׻�1X+��0J���A�\u0008��0�|…"
```

I have tried a numerous amount of ways to open this PDF in a new tab and have yet to have any success.

How can I replicate the previous behavior without using the `<form>` tag. I essentially am clicking a button and would like to open a new tab with the PDF.

I use the term "data object", but I really don't know what type of response I am getting back here (which is why it's hard to find an answer to my problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but why not just use a link open the pdf?

```
const href = `/pdf/company?ID=${record.id}&PAGE_ID=${this.props.pageID}`
return (
  <a href={href} target="_blank">Open PDF in new tab</a>
)
```

The `<form>` element feels like overkill for a simple get request

The data object you are referring to is the data stream of the binary or pdf as encoded text. You will see the same thing if you attempt to open an image in a text editor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character

Comment: as in a direct link to the pdf?

Comment: Yes. I actually had been brainstorming a solution to drop the GET request after I posted this question. The initial problem is that we have multiple domains and the sub domain in the pdf url has to match where it originated from. My solution was to use `window.location.href` and parse out the sub-domain, and hard code a url when it's being run locally.

Comment: Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: all sounds good in theory! give it a shot. im not clear why youd need the subdomain parsed if the pdf destination is path is relative rather than absolute

Comment: I did not write the original implementation of this, so unfortunately I don't fully understand why it's written this way and was unable to get a clear answer. Like I said this specific PDF is being sent over by a third party API that we use in our application. So we have a controller built to make this request and mask the url being show to our users on the PDF page.